# What is domain of power function, where exponent is infinity.

Tags: limits, infinity

Given the function $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} x^n$, what its domain is?

I have searched plenty materials implicitly contain this problem. They give out 2 different answer: $x\in [0,+\infty)$ and $x \in (-\infty, +\infty)$.
I have also learned conditions about $n=p/q$. Seemingly this doesn't help my problem. As $\infty$ is neither rational nor irrational.

I want to learn reasons of the answers, and citations.

---

In fact this question is extracted from $f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac { x^{2n-1} + x} {x^{2n}+1}$. My answer book says the domain is $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
In my brain I consider $f$'s domain is subject to $x^{2n}$, so come up with this question.
Moreover, I want to learn the generalized case. If a function is like $\lim_{n\to\infty} g(x^n)$, how I should consider the $x^n$ part.

Comment: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x^n$ exists and is a finite real number only when $-1<x\le1$ so the domain is $(-1,1]$. Also, $f(x)=0$ if $x\in(-1,1)$, and $f(1)=1$. This comment assumes $n\to\infty$ with integer values only.

Comment: @CameronBuie Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @Mirko Thanks for your note. You let me know I didn't ask the right way.